# Circuit breaker Pattern

Tags: java, microservices, hystrix, circuit-breaker

Is that fallback method and actual method should return same return type.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "reliable")
  public String readingList() {
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/recommended");

    return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
  }

  public String reliable() {
    return "Cloud Native Java (O'Reilly)";
  }
```

What I should do to return String from the fallback method `reading list` and return some Object from the actual method `reliable`?

Answer (score 3):

By definition fallback method means a substitution for real method if something were to happen.
You cannot return different type. It doesn't make any sense.
Hence method signature has to be exactly same with a few exceptions.

1. Return types has to be same or covariant
2. Method arguments has to be same. And you can add an extra argument of type `Throwable` to get the exception on which fallback was called.

Comment: It's OK to play with covariant return types though.